# how to put the fetched values in to variable with comma separation?

Tags: php

while working on tags process i got one problem . here i am using preg_match_all method for selecting particular tag.

after using that i am getting data like that . here posting the php code and output please check.

```
 <?php
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        preg_match_all("/(@\w+)/", $comment, $matches);
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($matches); 

?>
```

output:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @name
            [1] => @variables
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => @name
            [1] => @variables
        )

)
```

here i am getting doubt how to convert this array with comma separation.

expecting:

$tagging = (@name, @variables);

any one knows please help me how to solve like that.

Comment: loop the array and use implode to Join array elements with a string:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tagging = implode (",", $matches[1]); // '@name,@variables'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
preg_match_all("/(@\w+)/", $comment, $matches);

foreach($matches as $val){
    echo implode (",", $val);
    //echo '(' . implode (",", $val) . ')';
}
?>
```

Un-comment second line if you want paranthesis as well